# How to authenticate to ADLS from within spark job

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight, azure-data-lake

I am building a spark library which developers will use when writing their spark jobs to get access to data on Azure Data Lake. But the authentication will depend on the dataset they ask for. I need to call a rest API from within spark job to get credentials and authenticate to read data from ADLS. Is that even possible? I am new to spark.

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you actually intend to do. So here is a generic answer.

If your code is simply invoked through Spark and is able to access file systems then your job is really easy. On an HDInsight cluster you can directly access data by providing the adl:// URL in various locations. For your own Spark cluster you can connect it to ADLS by following instructions here: https://medium.com/azure-data-lake/connecting-your-own-hadoop-or-spark-to-azure-data-lake-store-93d426d6a5f4

Now if you're developing something else, you need to evaluate whether the environment you're executing in has access to the jars in the Spark classpath. Then you can use the ADLS Java SDK that is installed there and access ADLS.

Hope this is at least somewhat useful.